# Web scraping through API - Python - Requests Library

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, python-requests

Im new to python/development. As i started to read the requests module, i came across this weird website terion.in. Its a game website were the user has to guess the next sequence of colors. These color generate randomly based on the numbers. new set appears in 3 min of time gap. when i checked out the API, it was in Get method and i was able to scrape the data.

terion.in This website is a dummy shopping website, if logged in the game page appears.

```
import requests
 
headers = {
    'authority': 'booe.in',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'authorization': 'Token bee0043a8dd3413efa50e91853c6e9b1ca819a7e',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://booe.in/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,mt;q=0.8',
    'cookie': '__cfduid=d6548db2ec1334ee4806517500f0054fc1596897016; coem.notice.today=Important^%^20note^%^3A^%^20The^%^20recharge^%^20channel^%^20and^%^20withdrawal^%^20channel^%^20are^%^20maintained^%^20and^%^20upgraded.^%^20thank^%^20you^%^20for^%^20your^%^20support^!',
     
}
 
params = (
    ('category', 'P^'),
    ('p', '2^'),
    ('p_size', '2'),    
)
response = requests.get('https://booe.in/win/guesses', headers=headers, params=params)
json_response = response.json() 
json_response
```

output is like

```
{'code': 200,
'page': {'count': 44136, 'num_pages': 22068, 'current_page': 1},
'queryset': [{'period': 20200811455,
'price': 26324,
'last_num': 4,
'is_green': False,
'is_red': True,
'is_violet': False,
'create_time': '2020-08-11T22:45:02.736176+05:30'},
{'period': 20200811454,
'price': 26321,
'last_num': 1,
'is_green': True,
'is_red': False,
'is_violet': False,
'create_time': '2020-08-11T22:42:02.844054+05:30'}]}
```

So in this the next sequence generation will be '20200811456','20200811457',.....and so on.
the question is can i request a specific key - 'period number' and ask for value - 'result'?

Answer (score 0):

That depends purely on the API docs, that information should be on them, has nothing to do with python itself.